# Firefox extension not working

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon

I've created a Firefox extension but I can't use it (nothing happens).
 Does someone know why ?

The module hierarchy

my_firefox_extension

- chrome.manifest
- install.rdf
- chrome/

  - content/

    - locale.html
    - overlay.js
    - sample.xul

The code

chrome.manifest

```
content   firefox_extension chrome/content/

overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul  chrome://firefox_extension/content/sample.xul
```

install.rdf

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">

 <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
    <em:id>displaypages@bruno.com</em:id>
    <em:name>Display the page locale</em:name>
    <em:description>Welcome to this extension that displays the page locale when a user opens a new tab or windows</em:description>
    <em:version>0.1</em:version>
    <em:creator>Bruno Da Silva</em:creator>
    <em:homepageURL>https://www.example.com</em:homepageURL>
    <em:type>2</em:type>

    <!-- Mozilla Firefox -->
    <em:targetApplication>
    <Description>
       <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
       <em:minVersion>3.0</em:minVersion>
       <em:maxVersion>4.0.*</em:maxVersion>
    </Description>
       </em:targetApplication>
  </Description>
</RDF>
```

sample.xul

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<overlay id="firefox_extension-browser-overlay"
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

  <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://firefox_extension/content/overlay.js"/>

</overlay>
```

overlay.js

```
function Read(file)
{
     var ioService=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
                             .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
     var scriptableStream=Components
         .classes["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"]
         .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableInputStream);

     var channel=ioService.newChannel(file,null,null);
     var input=channel.open();
     scriptableStream.init(input);
     var str=scriptableStream.read(input.available());
     scriptableStream.close();
     input.close();
     return str;
 }

gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    var documentElement = e.originalTarget.defaultView.document;
    var div = documentElement.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = Read("chrome://firefox_extension/content/locale.html");
    documentElement.body.appendChild(div);
});
```

locale.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" >
   <head>
       <title>Page displayed when a user opens a new tab or window</title>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
   </head>
   <body>
         <p>Some text<p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: At what point do you get the error? If it's during installation, set the preference extensions.logging.enabled in about:config, then try again, and copy in the errors seen in the Error Console.

Comment: @Matthew Wilson During the installation. I've updated my post to put the messages I get in the Console.

Comment: What happens if you type `chrome://firefox_extension/content/overlay.js` on the address bar?

Comment: Maybe it is the invalid target version `<em:maxVersion>6.0a1</em:maxVersion>`. Try `<em:maxVersion>4.0.*</em:maxVersion>` instead.

Comment: The error messages are the same.

Comment: Could you post the XPI file somewhere?

Comment: Thanks everyone for trying to find the solution ! the extension : http://uploadingit.com/file/qvktprd9aidoasq9/my_firefox_extension.xpi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed one parameter which is probably causing the errors:

```
gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    var documentElement = e.originalTarget.defaultView.document;
    var div = documentElement.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = Read("chrome://firefox_extension/content/locale.html");
    documentElement.body.appendChild(div);
},

false // missing parameter on addEventListener
      // add this and it might work
);
```

Comment: Ah - good eyes!  No clues - you had to wade through someone else's code.  With 16.8k of points, the answer and time is an act of charity, not an act of points!

Answer (score 0):

(Just guessing, no testing involved)

`NS_ERROR_FILE_TARGET_DOES_NOT_EXIST` might be caused by incorrect script file reference in sample.xul

```
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome//firefox_extension/content/overlay.js"/>
```

`src` attribute is missing a colon after "chrome". It should be

```
src="chrome://firefox_extension/content/overlay.js"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried it and it doesn't work (I get the same message error as before).

Answer (score 0):

The files in firefox could be corrected .

Try the following

Exit Firefox completely, then open your Firefox profile folder and delete or rename these files:

extensions.ini 
extensions.cache 
extensions.rdf

Starting in Firefox 4, also delete or rename:

extensions.sqlite 
extensions.sqlite-journal (if found)

**Note: Although the above files can be deleted, renaming them (e.g., "extensionsOLD.ini", "extensionsOLD.cache", etc.) is generally considered a safer option. This achieves the same result, but allows the user to retrieve any possibly required information from them later on.**

Then try to restart the browser and install them

Else there is another method which may work (but dont know why/how they work)

Enable third party cookies - go to Tools -> Options -> Privacy and check the Accept third-party cookies box.

Comment: try setting `extensions.checkCompatibility` attribute to false in firefox configuration file. Anyway, can you please post the exact error it shows while installing

Comment: In the tab warning I get the exact two warnings I've put in the post. Thanks for your other sugggestion I'm going to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Does you extension work when using it in a [live development environment](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Getting_started_with_extension_development#Registering_your_extension_in_the_Extension_Manager), as opposed to having issues with the xpi installer?

> With Firefox closed, create a
>   “pointer” file with the same name as
>   your extension’s Description:ID (as
>   found in your install.rdf) in profile
>   folder/extensions/ and edit it so that
>   it contains the path to your
>   extension’s folder (the root
>   containing containing install.rdf and
>   chrome.manifest files).
>
> E.g. helloworld’s ID is
>   helloworld@mozilla.doslash.org and we
>   would like to register it in
>   X:\Dev\helloworld\ (i.e. there is
>   X:\Dev\helloworld\install.rdf file
>   etc.). Just put a single line into the
>   file at this path: profile
>   folder/extensions/helloworld@mozilla.doslash.org
>
> X:\Dev\helloworld\ - note trailing
>   slash and no CR; this must be a SINGLE LINE
>
> (Re)Start Firefox, and check that your
>   extension is installed.

This will help you make sure that the extension works, before you start tackling installation issues.