# Firefox code displaying user bookmarks not working

Tags: javascript, api, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm using some code in a Firefox extension to display the bookmarks of an user but it's not working (the text "some text" appears on the page but not the bookmarks), does someone know why ?

the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" >
<head>
   <title>Page displayed when a user opens a new tab or window</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

   <script type="text/javascript">

       function init() {
         var historyService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/browser/nav-history-service;1"]
                                     .getService(Components.interfaces.nsINavHistoryService);
         var options = historyService.getNewQueryOptions();
         var query = historyService.getNewQuery();

         var bookmarksService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/browser/nav-bookmarks-service;1"]
                                         .getService(Components.interfaces.nsINavBookmarksService);
         var toolbarFolder = bookmarksService.toolbarFolder;

         query.setFolders([toolbarFolder], 1);

         var result = historyService.executeQuery(query, options);
         var rootNode = result.root;
         rootNode.containerOpen = true;

         // iterate over the immediate children of this folder and dump to console
         output.innerHTML+='test';

         for (var i = 0; i < rootNode.childCount; i ++) {
           var node = rootNode.getChild(i);
             output.innerHTML+='test'; // not working
             output.innerHTML+=("Child: " + node.title + "\n"); //not working
            //dump("Child: " + node.title + "\n"); not working
         }

         // close a container after using it!
         rootNode.containerOpen = false
         }

   </script>
</head>
       <body onload="init()">
          <p>Some text<p>
          <div id="output">
          </div>
       </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "is not working" tells us really much - please be more specific if you prefer an answer over downvotes

Comment: Bruno, I've been following your questions, I think you need to digest more Firefox tutorials. My favorite turorial is this: http://presentation-slides.googlecode.com/files/how-to-write-your-first-extension-berlin.pdf. In the init() method, you're trying to access Firefox APIs (such as the bookmark service) in the context of a web page. That's not going to work. Instead you'll need to overlay browser.xul, register an event handler to be notified of newly opened tabs, query the bookmark service, generate the html code that displays the bookmarks, and display that.

Comment: @speedball Thanks for the advice ! I'm going head first on the tutorial :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the code to the overlay file, it works ! (to see the entire extension [Firefox extension not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881833/firefox-extension-not-working))

code :

```
function Read(file)
{
   var ioService=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
       .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
   var scriptableStream=Components
       .classes["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"]
       .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableInputStream);

   var channel=ioService.newChannel(file,null,null);
   var input=channel.open();
   scriptableStream.init(input);
   var str=scriptableStream.read(input.available());
   scriptableStream.close();
   input.close();
   return str;
}

gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    var documentElement = e.originalTarget.defaultView.document;
    var div = documentElement.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = Read("chrome://firefox_extension/content/locale.html");


    var historyService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/browser/nav-history-service;1"]
                                   .getService(Components.interfaces.nsINavHistoryService);
    var options = historyService.getNewQueryOptions();
    var query = historyService.getNewQuery();

    var bookmarksService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/browser/nav-bookmarks-service;1"]
                                     .getService(Components.interfaces.nsINavBookmarksService);
    var toolbarFolder = bookmarksService.toolbarFolder;

    query.setFolders([toolbarFolder], 1);

    var result = historyService.executeQuery(query, options);
    var rootNode = result.root;
    rootNode.containerOpen = true;

    // iterate over the immediate children of this folder and dump to console
    for (var i = 0; i < rootNode.childCount; i ++) {
       var node = rootNode.getChild(i);
       var $i = documentElement.createElement("div");
       $i.innerHTML+=("Child: " + node.title + "\n");
       documentElement.body.appendChild($i);
     }

    // close a container after using it!
    rootNode.containerOpen = false;

    documentElement.body.appendChild(div);
},

false

);
```

Comment: If this answer is the solution to your problem, click the green checkmark next to it! =)