# why some breakpoint in firefox extension not works?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-developer-tools

line 22 break point works when i click the addone button, 
**but how to enter break point at line 1 and line 2? seems i cannot enter these break points, why? then, how to enter these break points?**
[image]

btw, this question is not the same as [Firefox extension not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881833/firefox-extension-not-working), but if i enable line 5, the button of this addone cannot be found, that's why i set break point at line 1 and 2, in order to know why i cannot enable line 5-8, which is really confusing